# virtualenv(python3.4), pip install mysqlclient error

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv

I created virtualenv for django 1.9 project. I am trying to pip install mysqlclient  or mysql-python but both of them gives me errors.

```
pip install mysqlclient

pip install mysql-python
```

both give me the same error message:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/r4/bkv_4t9s4r140pjkgv6lsq8w0000gn/T/pip-build-cdxcssp9/mysqlclient

any suggestions!?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try to run this before:

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip install pymysql
pip install mysqlclient
```

In OSX:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Comment: the first two commands give me,
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package python-dev
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package libmysqlclient-dev..

Comment: So, run `brew install mysql-connector-c`

Comment: any suggestions on how to do it for centos 7?

Comment: @arcegk this should be an answer! only this really helped me.

Comment: Here is my solution: 
https://saugatbhattarai.com.np/error-while-installing-mysqlclient-in-virtualenv/

Comment: The macOS one really helped me. It works now! Just make sure after you install the second one with brew you set up the environment variables how it suggests there

Answer (score 5):

This is probably due to your `mysql_config` being broken.

As of 2019, here is how to run smoothly `pip install mysqlclient` on MacOS:

`brew info openssl` and follow the commands at the bottom

```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Other approaches:

- `brew install/upgrade/reinstall mysql` : did not fix the issue for me, but has the nice side effect to make sure your installation is clean.
- `brew install mysql-connector-c` : to make that work you have to unlink mysql, which ruins your setup and it did not fix the issue for me.

Comment: Hi, are these steps valid?
I'm having tough time setting up a django project with mysql, absolutely nothing is working for me

Comment: Is your brew up to date ? What the error you're having ??

Comment: I had the error `ld: library not found for -lssl` in MacOS 10.15. This answer worked for me, but I had to append both `export LDFLAGS` and `export CPPFLAGS` in `~/.bashrc` file, to export the variables permanently

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Anaconda (which I highly suggest you) then run these two commands

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
```

and

```
conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the MySQL APT repository config tool (you can see more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/)

   ```
   wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
   ```
2. Install the MySQL APT repository config tool

   ```
   dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
   ```

You will be asked to select product and version that you want to install. In the first step, select Server and next select either mysql-5.6 or mysql-5.7. Then click Apply.

3. Update APT

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
4. Install the server

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-community-server

   sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
   sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
   pip install pymysql
   pip install mysqlclient
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2.x, and already have installed:

- MySQL Server
- Python Connector

Then the problem is when you run:

Windows:

```
(your environment) SomePath> pip install mysqlclient
```

Mac OS:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

Actually it is asking to install package for Python 3.x not 2.x. So it is throwing an error.

**Solution** is to run:

Windows:

```
(your environment) SomePath> pip install mysqlclient==1.3.9
```

Mac OS:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient==1.3.9
```

P.S The *mysqlclient==1.3.9* version is the latest version for Python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip install pymysql
pip install mysqlclient
```

and setup

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for on Ubuntu 18.04

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev 
sudo apt-get install mysql-client 
sudo apt-get install libsqlclient-dev 
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Python 3.12 and Ubuntu 22.04 WSL.

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev
sudo apt-get install -y gcc default-libmysqlclient-dev pkg-config
pip install mysqlclient
```